# To be ordered or not to be ordered

Tags: probability

This is the general format of many probability questions:

> From the given $N$ distinct numbers, $n$ distinct numbers are ***randomly selected*** such that...

OR

> $a_1 ,a_2 ,a_3,...,a_n$ are $n$ distinct numbers ***randomly selected*** from $N$ distinct numbers, such that...

OR any other that I'm yet to see.

**My question:**

> When do I treat these $n$ numbers as an ordered set of numbers, and when do I not?

i.e. to say, for $n=4$, $(5,6,7,8)$ is not the same as $(6,7,8,5)$ if these are ordered pairs.

I ask this question because when sets become ordered, their count, hence probability

($=\frac{\text{count favored}}{\text{total count}}$) changes. I need to know if there exist "signals" (word usage patterns) in probability questions from which I can infer that the answer has to be derived using ordered pair or un ordered pair.

Comment: ... that's the question. Appreciated humor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, when **probability** is asked for, it doesn't matter !

**Q:** *Pr* that we get $5,6,7,8$ when $4$ distinct digits are randomly selected from the $10$ decimal digits.

(a) When the order in which you select the digits doesn't matter: $\dfrac{1}{\binom{10}4}$

(b) When the order in which you select the digits matters: $\dfrac{4!}{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7}$

Comment: How are you defining a "favorable outcome" in this case?

Comment: Actually, you hadn't framed the full question. I have edited my answer to frame a specific question which should clarify your doubts. Pl. note that while the probability is the same for the two cases, the **count** of favorable outcomes and total outcomes are **not** the same. If you are interested in the **count**, words like "select", "choose" etc point to combinations, while "arranged", "ordered" etc point to permutations.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing is said about the order, then you can assume the order doesn't count.